# comparing in the same table based on latest creation date

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id|code|transaction_date   |amount|status|record_status|creation_date
1 |0001|2021-12-10 00:00:00| 10.00|Succ  |D            |2021-12-10 00:00:00
2 |0001|2021-12-10 00:00:00| 10.00|Fail  |D            |2021-12-11 00:00:00
3 |0001|2021-12-10 00:00:00| 10.00|      |A            |2021-12-12 00:00:00
```

I want to select recod_status = A, code = 001 and transaction date is 2021-12-10'

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
WHERE DATE(alloc.trans_date) IN ('2021-12-10') // Need filter by few dates
AND record_status = 'A'
AND code = '001';
```

but I only want the record to return if the same code = 001 and transaction date is 2021-12-10' but record_status = 'D', status = 'Fail' and the creation_date is latest.

Example above will return 3rd record because 2nd record which creation_date is the latest and status = 'Fail' and record_status = 'D'.

I just want to compare the latest creation_date.'

I can select the latest transaction where the record_status = 'D'

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable
WHERE creation_date = (
  SELECT MAX(creation_date)
  FROM TestTable
  WHERE DATE(trans_date) IN ('2021-12-10')
  AND record_status = 'D'
)
AND record_status = 'D'
AND code = '001';
```

Comment: *because 2nd record which creation_date is the latest* ??? The latest `creation_date` value is `'2021-12-12 00:00:00'` which belongs to row `id=3`, not 2...

Comment: The latest for record_status = D

Comment: Yes I want to return the last record where record status = A when the previous record (latest creation  date) status = Fail

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? If the latest row has D, pre-last has A and pre-pre-last has D then do you need pre-last to be returned? If the latest row and pre-last one have A and pre-pre-last has D then do you need the most last or pre-last to be returned?

Comment: MYSQL 5, I just want to compare the 3rd (record_status=A) with the 2nd row, because 2nd row is the last creation date and record_status=D, and both has the same transaction date. But retuen only when the 2nd row status is 'FAIL'. My last sql statement is to select last record where record_status is 'D'

Comment: Does `(transaction_date, creation_date)` is unique?

Comment: transaction_date, creation_date) is not unique

Answer (score 1):

Looks like:

```sql
SELECT t1.*  
-- or SELECT t2.* - depends on the task which is unclear for me yet
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM table
       WHERE DATE(trans_date) = '2021-12-10'
       ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 1 ) t1
JOIN table t2 ON DATE(t1.trans_date) = DATE(t2.trans_date)
             AND t1.creation_date > t2.creation_date
WHERE t1.record_status = 'A'
  AND t2.record_status = 'D'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t3
                   WHERE DATE(t1.trans_date) = DATE(t3.trans_date)
                     AND t1.creation_date > t3.creation_date
                     AND t3.creation_date > t2.creation_date )
```

Subquery `t1` selects the most last row, and further it is checked for status A.
Table copy `t2` selects the row which is adjacent to the row selected in subquery (`NOT EXISTS` checks that there is no any row between), and further it is checked for status D.